# Flash Lightbox script for an image + movie gallery

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, lightbox, gallery

For a CDROM i'm working on, i'm looking for a method to display images with a lightbox effect. What is the best way to do it with AS3? Is there an AS3 lightbox script available?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you are in luck, there is a script and a tutorial available out there, which can be found [here](http://www.pr13.org/tutorials/?p=6). It is clearly explained step-by-step, and you can download an example of it, which runs exactly how you'd expect a lightbox to run. It should and will work on your CD-ROM.

Best of luck.